# snowflake role: not giving select access to tables moved into the schema from another schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake i have a role given select access to all the tables inside a schema `SCHEMA1`

```
  GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE DB1 TO test_role;
  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA DB1.SCHEMA1 TO test_role;
  GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA DB1.SCHEMA1 TO ROLE test_role;
```

I have three tables inside them

but when I a move a table into this schema from another schema its not getting the select access

```
  alter table if exists "DB1"."SCHEMA2"."table1" RENAME TO "DB1"."SCHEMA1"."table4";
```

i am expecting all tables to have select access inside this schema "SCHEMA1".

Also i observed those created inside the schema directly are having select access, but those which have been moved using alter are not getting the select access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am expecting all tables to have select access inside this schema
> "SCHEMA1".
>
> Also i observed those created inside the schema directly are having
> select access, but those which have been moved using alter are not
> getting the select access.

When you create a table, it doesn't come with additional grants (such as SELECT) except ownership. You said that the tables created inside the schema have SELECT access, so I suspect FUTURE GRANTS are applied for that schema.

The rename operation doesn't trigger "future grants":

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#restrictions-limitations

In this case, you need to grant the required SELECT permissions.

Comment: `FUTURE GRANTS`  are given. thats why i think create statement is having select access. `The rename operation doesn't trigger "future grants":`  - got it. thanks